# Silverlight Library to create Tree Graphs

Tags: silverlight

We are looking for a SilverLight library that will allow us to create graphs that describe relationships in terms of linked nodes. I was hoping that someone could suggest one if it exists.

An example of what I'm looking for would be [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/); which is a java library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com) is a free, open source one with support from some Microsoft employees.

> QuickGraph provides generic
> directed/undirected graph
> datastructures and algorithms for .Net
> 2.0 and up.
>
> QuickGraph comes with algorithms such as depth first seach,
> breath first search, A* search,
> shortest path, k-shortest path,
> maximum flow, minimum spanning tree,
> least common ancestors, etc...
>
> QuickGraph supports MSAGL, GLEE, and
> Graphviz to render the graphs,
> serialization to GraphML, etc...
>
> QuickGraph supports .NET 3.5 and up,
> and Silverlight 3 and 4.
>
> QuickGraph is
> annotated with Code Contracts. Other
> projects using QuickGraph
> Reflector.Graph Addin Graph#, layout
> algorithms Jolt.Net, a backing store
> for a generic finite state machine
> implementation JSL StyleCop, Custom
> rules for Microsoft's StyleCop utility
> NDepend, codebase macro analysis

Comment: Thanks. This looks perfect. Have you used this library? My only concern is with how this library treats each vertex. Can the vertices be a custom type? The examples show a factory pattern in which a vertex is given and its type is not user defined. Thanks!

Comment: I've dabbled with it. I am building a large graph (see http://commandments.codeplex.com) and have dabbled with using QuickGraph with it. I don't know whether each vertex can be a custom type. I believe there's a QuickGraph forum, and also the QuickGraph site on codeplex has forums for these sort of questions. Jonathan deHalleux, one of the primary maintainers of QuickGraph, should be able to help you from here.